# Is my skip-list really searching in N rather than log(N)?

Tags: c, data-structures, time, time-complexity, skip-lists

So I finally thought I finished creating a working skip-list and figured I should check my work and look into timing the search function. I found a tutorial for how to use `clock()` and implemented it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "skiplist.h"

int main() {
    // initialize
    SkipList *list = initSkipList();
    // numbers to search for, array to store time
    int n[] = {1, 10, 50, 100, 1000, 5000, 10000, 25000, 50000, 100000, 200000};
    double time[11];

    // insert
    for (int i = 1; i <= 200000; i++)
        insertElement(list, i);

    // search, time, print
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        clock_t t;
        t = clock();
        findElement(list, n[i]);
        t = clock() - t;
        double time_taken = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in seconds
        ti[i] = time_taken;
        printf("fun() took %f seconds to execute \n", time_taken);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I thought by doing this and plotting N vs. time I would get a graph that looks logarithmic, but instead my  graph looks linear:

[image]

Do I have a misunderstanding about how I should go about timing my functions to try and test time-complexity or is my skip-list just not searching as it should be? Here's my entire skip-list implementation just in case, but the search function is called `findElement()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#ifndef SKIPLIST_H_
#define SKIPLIST_H_


// number of lists
#define MAXLEVEL 5 

// node with pointers
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next[1]; // or C99 using flexible array members: *next[]
} Node;


// skiplist
typedef struct SkipList {
    Node *header;
    int level;
    int count;
} SkipList;


// initialize skip list
SkipList* initSkipList() {  
    int i;
    SkipList *list = calloc(1, sizeof(SkipList));
    if (!list) {
        printf("Memory Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //list->level = 0;  
    if ((list->header = calloc(1, sizeof(Node) + MAXLEVEL*sizeof(Node*))) == 0) {
        printf("Memory Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }   
    for (i = 0; i <= MAXLEVEL; i++)
        list->header->next[i] = list->header;   // or = list->header?
    printf("Skip list initialized.\n");
    //srand(time(NULL));
    return list;
}

// insert into skip list, return pointer to node
Node* insertElement(SkipList *list,int data) {
    int i, newLevel;
    Node* temp = list->header;
    Node *update[MAXLEVEL+1];

    // find where data belongs
    for (i = list->level; i >= 0; i--) {
        while(temp->next[i] != list->header && temp->next[i]->data < data)
            temp = temp->next[i];
        update[i] = temp;
    }
    temp = temp->next[0];
    // if element already exists, just return it (no duplicates)
    if (temp != list->header && temp->data == data)
        return temp;

    // determine level (coin flips till failure or max level reached)
    for (newLevel = 0; (rand() < RAND_MAX/2) && (newLevel < MAXLEVEL); newLevel++); // Pr(4) == Pr(5)??
    if (newLevel > list->level) {
        for (i = list->level + 1; i <= newLevel; i++)
            update[i] =  list->header;
        list->level = newLevel;
    }

    // make new  node
    if ((temp = calloc(1, sizeof(Node) + newLevel*sizeof(Node*))) == 0) {
        printf("Memory Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    temp->data = data;
    list->count++;
    // update next links
    for (i = 0; i <= newLevel; i++) {
        temp->next[i] = update[i]->next[i];
        update[i]->next[i] = temp;
    }

    //printf("Element %d inserted into list. (level %d)\n", data, newLevel);
    return temp;
}


// delete node containing data
void deleteElement(SkipList *list, int data) {
    int i;
    Node *update[MAXLEVEL+1], *temp;
    temp = list->header;
    for (i = list->level; i >= 0; i--) {
        while (temp->next[i] != list->header && temp->next[i]->data < data)
            temp = temp->next[i];
        update[i] = temp;
    }
    // move to (possible) node to delete
    temp = temp->next[0];
    // if doesn't exist
    if (temp == list->header || temp->data != data) {
        printf("Element %d doesn't exist.\n", data);    
        return;
    }
    // adjust next pointers
    for (i = 0; i <= list->level; i++) {
        if (update[i]->next[i] != temp) break;
        update[i]->next[i] = temp->next[i];
    }
    free (temp);
    printf("Element %d deleted from list.\n", data);
    list->count--;
    // adjust header level
    while ((list->level > 0) && (list->header->next[list->level] == list->header)) // double check
        list->level--;
}


// find node containing data
Node* findElement(SkipList *list, int data){
    int i;
    Node *temp = list->header;
    for (i = list->level; i >= 0; i--) {
        while (temp->next[i] != list->header && temp->next[i]->data < data)
            temp = temp->next[i];
    }
    temp = temp->next[0];
    if (temp != list->header && temp->data == data) {
        printf("Element %d found and returned.\n", data);
        return (temp);
    }
    printf("Element %d not found.\n", data);
    return 0;
}


/* Dynamic array for use in printSkipList() function */
typedef struct {
    int *array;
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
} Array;
void initArray(Array *a, size_t initialSize) {
    a->array = malloc(initialSize * sizeof(int));
    a->used = 0;
    a->size = initialSize;
}
void insertArray(Array *a, int element) {
    if (a->used == a->size) {
        a->size *= 2;
        a->array = realloc(a->array, a->size * sizeof(int));
    }
    a->array[a->used++] = element;
}
void freeArray(Array *a) {
    free(a->array);
    a->array = NULL;
    a->used = a->size = 0;
}


// print skip-list info and representational figure
void printSkipList(SkipList *list) {
    int i, j, k, pos = 0, prevPos = 0, diff, numDigits;
    Node* temp = list->header;
    Array a;

    // fill dynamic array with level 0 elements
    initArray(&a, 10);
    while (temp->next[0] != list->header) {
        temp = temp->next[0];
        insertArray(&a, temp->data);
    }
    temp = list->header;
    // print number of levels
    printf("\nNumber of levels in skip-list: %d\n", list->level + 1);
    printf("Number of elements in skip-list: %d\n", list->count);
    printf("Skip-list figure: \n");
    // print data
    for (i = list->level; i >= 0; i--) {
        pos = 0, prevPos = 0;
        while (temp->next[i] != list->header) {
        numDigits = 0;      
            temp = temp->next[i];
            while (temp->data != a.array[pos]) {
                numDigits += floor (log10 (abs (a.array[pos]))) + 1;
                pos++;
            }
            pos++;
            diff = (pos - prevPos) - 1; 
            if (diff >= 1) {
                for (j = 0; j < (4*diff)+numDigits; j++) 
                        printf(" ");    
            }           
            printf("%d -> ", temp->data);
            prevPos = pos;
        }
        temp = list->header;
        printf("\n");       
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

#endif // SKIPLIST_H_
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I think it might have to do with me having `MAXLEVEL` set to 5, but should this be a number I choose or something that should change based on the size of the skip-list? The other implementations I'm finding don't seem having a changing max level size, but I thought the optimal number would depend on the list.

Comment: Rather than asking us, why not hook up your debugger and see if your find method is hitting the higher level links? Or put in some debug code that outputs each link, along with the link level, as it's being followed.

Comment: Well first I wanted to know if the way I obtained the times even made sense or if there was some aspect I hadn't considered. I did try some print statements for debugging on a smaller sized list and it seems that it follows the path I expected it to, whether that is how it's actually supposed to work is a different story though. I'll keep thinking about how to debug, but when I increase the number of elements enough to get significant time readings to plot, it becomes harder for me to try and follow.

Comment: You might also consider running, say, 10,000 iterations of your test in a loop, and averaging the times. So you'd search for all 11 numbers, then again, etc. Having just one data point for each number isn't a particularly good test.

Comment: `printf()` is a sink hole of CPU time.  Remove from `findElement()` to gauge raw performance.

Comment: @JimMischel That's true I should have thought of that, thanks. Chux I commented out the print statements from my insert function, I guess I should remove every print statement and put them at the end though, thanks.

Comment: Better yet, in `findElement()` loop `while (temp->next[i] != list->header && temp->next[i]->data < data)  temp = temp->next[i];`, put a `count++` and use _that_ to gauge performance.

Comment: Ah that's a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MAXLEVEL is way too small. I think original paper had the level at up to lg(n), that is log base 2 of the list size.

From Puch's original 1990 skiplist paper:

> Determining MaxLevel
>
> Since we can safely cap levels at L(n), we should
>   choose MaxLevel = L(N) (where N is an upper bound on the number of
>   elements in a skip list). If p = l/2, using MaxLevel = 16 is
>   appropriate for data structures containing up to 2^16 elements

In general, if p is 1/X, then use log base X of the list size.

MAXLEVEL=5, and I get about the same results you see.

```
evaitl@bb ~/se $ ./foo 
Skip list initialized.
Element 1 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000014 seconds to execute 
Element 10 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000002 seconds to execute 
Element 50 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000002 seconds to execute 
Element 100 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000002 seconds to execute 
Element 1000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000003 seconds to execute 
Element 5000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000004 seconds to execute 
Element 10000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000006 seconds to execute 
Element 25000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000011 seconds to execute 
Element 50000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000021 seconds to execute 
Element 100000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000044 seconds to execute 
Element 200000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000087 seconds to execute
```

Raised the MAXLEVEL to 20, and I get:

```
evaitl@bb ~/se $ ./foo 
Skip list initialized.
Element 1 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000016 seconds to execute 
Element 10 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000003 seconds to execute 
Element 50 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000003 seconds to execute 
Element 100 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000002 seconds to execute 
Element 1000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000002 seconds to execute 
Element 5000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000003 seconds to execute 
Element 10000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000004 seconds to execute 
Element 25000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000003 seconds to execute 
Element 50000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000004 seconds to execute 
Element 100000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000003 seconds to execute 
Element 200000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000004 seconds to execute
```

Added 400000 and 800000 to your n[]:

```
evaitl@bb ~/se $ ./foo 
Skip list initialized.
Element 1 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000016 seconds to execute 
Element 10 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000001 seconds to execute 
Element 50 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000001 seconds to execute 
Element 100 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000002 seconds to execute 
Element 1000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000002 seconds to execute 
Element 5000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000002 seconds to execute 
Element 10000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000002 seconds to execute 
Element 25000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000004 seconds to execute 
Element 50000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000003 seconds to execute 
Element 100000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000003 seconds to execute 
Element 200000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000003 seconds to execute 
Element 400000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000004 seconds to execute 
Element 800000 found and returned.
fun() took 0.000003 seconds to execute
```

Comment: Thanks I think this is the info I needed, I never thought to look up the original paper.I'll probably either add another input to make MAXSIZE a variable that is log2(n) the expected list size, or just make it very large.

Answer (score 1):

Your timing method is unconventional.
Generally, to check algorithm performance, you

- take the average of several attempts.
- time the performance of several different sized containers.

In pseudocode:

```
For N in [2..9]:
  Fill container with 10^N items
  lookupTime = 0;
  generate M values in range
  for i in [1..M]:
    lookupTime += duration(lookup(value[i]))
  performance[N] = lookupTime/M;
```

Comment: Thanks I'll do this. I notice that I get substantially improved performance if I change `MAXLEVEL` to a much higher number. I guess this is a tradeoff between time and space complexity? Do you happen to know what this should be set to compared to my list size to achieve the standard log(n) search? Neither my book nor the wikipedia article seems to mention this. Also is it better for this to be defined as a constant like I have it, or should it be variable in some way?

Comment: I think that if you have a 1/X chance of picking the next highest level, then the max level should be log base X of N, the list size. (1/2 chance ==> lg(N).